# Selenium does NOT do anything after getting rid of GDPR consent

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe

It's my first time using Selenium and webscraping. I have been stuck with the annoying GDPR iframe. I am simply trying to go to a website, search something in the search bar and then click in one of the results. But it does not seem to do anything after I get rid of the GDPR consent.

Important, it does not give any errors.

This is my very simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

#Web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://transfermarkt.co.uk/")

search = driver.find_element_by_name("query")
search.send_keys("Sevilla FC")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "sp_message_iframe_382445")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='ACCEPT ALL']"))).click()

try:
    sevfclink = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "368")))
    sevfclink.click()
except:
    driver.quit()

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Is this all your code? What line is it failing on? I'm assuming if you let it sit for 10s+, it will finally timeout and give you an error but you stated that you aren't getting any errors. With an ID of 368, that doesn't seem like it's going to be a stable locator. I would find another way to locate whatever element that is.

Comment: you never switch the driver out of the iframe.  Is that by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you get the iframe from but the id might be dynamic so try this.

```
driver.get("https://transfermarkt.co.uk/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "query")))
search.send_keys("Sevilla FC", Keys.RETURN)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='sp_message_iframe']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='ACCEPT ALL']"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
try:
    sevfclink = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "368")))
    sevfclink.click()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: This worked fine! I need to study your code... there are few things I haven't encountered yet. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the two lines starting WebDriverWait throw an error. If I skip those to the try statement you get the results of the search. A page that gives an overview of Sevilla FC shows up. I presume the WebDriverWait lines are there to make sure you wait for something, but from what I can tell they are unnecessary.